# Does aria-hidden="true" hides the element from all user agents or only screen-readers?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I read in some posts([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933265/3429430) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31383333/3429430)) that `aria-hidden="true"` hides the element from all user agents.

> aria-hidden (state): Indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible or perceivable to any user as implemented by the author.

- Does `aria-hidden="true"` hides the element from all user agents or only screen-readers?
- If yes, then in bootstrap why is the glyphicon inside the `carousel-control` icon visible even with the attribute `aria-hedden="true"`?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the official documentation states that **element and all of its descendants are not visible**, elements with `aria-hidden="true"` tags are indeed visible in all modern browsers.

But elements with this tag will be invisible to accessibility tools, such as screen readers.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/92s2q861/

Further, using `visibility: hidden;` o̶r̶ ̶`̶d̶i̶s̶p̶l̶a̶y̶:̶ ̶n̶o̶n̶e̶`̶
 CSS attributes will hide the element from he user when the DOM is rendered in the browser. But witout `aria-hidden="true"` tag, that element will be detected by the accessibility tools.

UPDATE:  `display: none` will hide the element when DOM is rendered in browser and the element will be ignored by the accessibility tools as well.

Comment: Are you sure that elements with `display:none` will be detected by screen readers(accessibility tools)? `display: none` diminishes the element from the document flow. And css tricks says something else https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry abut the confusion. I have updated the answer. `display: none` hides the element from the screen readers as well. Tested it withe default screen reader in Ubuntu.

Comment: How did you type that weird deleted  display none?

Comment: The benevolent Unicode deity has blessed us with s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ characters. (http://adamvarga.com/strike/)